# How do I set up postfix to send mail through it?

Tags: mail, postfix

I have tried different tutorials, but at the end it always gives me errors when I test it using "telnet "myname" 25...I need help. I want a simple tutorial through which I can set up postfix on ubuntu and send mail through it?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a tutorial to install postfix and use virtual users and domains (e-mail accounts managed in MySQL) that I find a lot easier to manage than creating linux users for all the email accounts. It's a complete tutorial installing courier (for pop) and webmail (squirrelmail) but you can use only what you need to install.

[postfix-mysql-courier-webmail install from howtoforge](http://www.howtoforge.com/virtual-users-and-domains-with-postfix-courier-mysql-and-squirrelmail-ubuntu-11.10)

Comment: While useful, I find this answer overkill for the question.

Comment: I don't think because the question is about installing postfix and not choosing a mail server. I agree Postfix is overkill to only send mails through it, mainly if using only 1 user and 1 domain but configuring virtual users/domains adds only a little to postfix only configuration wich is not very easy and the result is a lot easier to administer if needs growing and adding users or domains.