# cannot send mail to localhost with postfix: Temporary lookup failure

Tags: package-management, email, postfix

I removed postfix, tried [Apache James](http://james.apache.org/server/3/quick-start.html), removed James, and now cannot get postfix working again:

to my knowledge, I'm using postfix correctly as so:

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ telnet localhost 25
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 dur.bounceme.net ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)
ehlo test
250-dur.bounceme.net
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
quit
221 2.0.0 Bye
Connection closed by foreign host.
thufir@dur:~$
```

**Possibly the problem is that sendmail isn't working:**

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ postfix sendmail
postfix: error: to submit mail, use the Postfix sendmail command
postfix: fatal: the postfix command is reserved for the superuser
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ sudo postfix sendmail
postfix/postfix-script: error: unknown command: 'sendmail'
postfix/postfix-script: fatal: usage: postfix start (or stop, reload, abort, flush, check, status, set-permissions, upgrade-configuration)
thufir@dur:~$
```

Telnet gives:

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ telnet localhost 25
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 dur.bounceme.net ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)
helo localhost
250 dur.bounceme.net
mail from:thufir@localhost
250 2.1.0 Ok
rcpt to:thufir@localhost
451 4.3.0 <thufir@localhost>: Temporary lookup failure
quit
221 2.0.0 Bye
Connection closed by foreign host.
thufir@dur:~$
```

**which definitely seems intriguing.**

Comment: The logs you have submitted instruct you to use postfix sendmail. Have you tried to do so?

Comment: I am using postfix, at least telnet shows that.  Doesn't it?

Comment: You are indeed using postfix. However the logs you submitted prove the existance of this command: postfix sendmail Have you tried to use it?

Comment: ok, I'm maybe using postfix incorrectly.  I want to send/receive to user@localhost with postfix.  referencing http://askubuntu.com/a/95974/45156 which I'm going through now.  I only need CLI access, though, no squirrel mail or courier, though.

Answer (score 1):

ok, it was a problem with installing postfix.  I fixed a config file, removed and re-installed:

```
root@dur:/etc/postfix# 
root@dur:/etc/postfix# diff main.cf main.cf.2
7c7
< #myorigin = /etc/mailname
---
> myorigin = /etc/mailname
40a41,94
> 
> 
> 
> ###adding###
> 
> 
> # Requirements for the HELO statement
> smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, warn_if_reject reject_non_fqdn_hostname, reject_invalid_hostname, permit 
> # Requirements for the sender details
> smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, warn_if_reject reject_non_fqdn_sender, reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_unauth_pipelining, permit
> # Requirements for the connecting server
> smtpd_client_restrictions = reject_rbl_client sbl.spamhaus.org, reject_rbl_client blackholes.easynet.nl, reject_rbl_client dnsbl.njabl.org
> # Requirement for the recipient address
> smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining, permit_mynetworks, reject_non_fqdn_recipient, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_unauth_destination, permit smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining
> 
> 
> 
> 
> # require proper helo at connections
> # smtpd_helo_required = yes
> # waste spammers time before rejecting them
> # smtpd_delay_reject = yes
> # disable_vrfy_command = yes
> 
> 
> 
> # not sure of the difference of the next two 
> # but they are needed for local aliasing 
> alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases 
> alias_database = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases 
> # this specifies where the virtual mailbox folders will be located 
> virtual_mailbox_base = /var/spool/mail/virtual 
> # this is for the mailbox location for each user 
> virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_mailbox.cf 
> # and this is for aliases virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_alias.cf 
> # and this is for domain lookups virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_domains.cf 
> # this is how to connect to the domains (all virtual, but the option is there) 
> # not used yet 
> # transport_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_transport.cf
> 
> 
> virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
> virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> # to add if there is not a virtual user 
> # sudo mkdir /var/spool/mail/virtual sudo groupadd --system virtual -g 5000 
> # sudo useradd --system virtual -u 5000 -g 5000 
> # sudo chown -R virtual:virtual /var/spool/mail/virtual
> 
> inet_protocols = ipv4
root@dur:/etc/postfix# 
root@dur:/etc/postfix# aptitude install -y  mysqmail-postfix-logger   postfix-mysql  mailutils
```

after which I read my inbox as so:

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ mail
"/var/mail/thufir": 4 messages 4 new
>N   1 hawat@localhost    Sat Aug 25 17:04  16/565   hello world
 N   2 thufir             Sat Aug 25 17:05  13/428   cannot send to localhost
 N   3 thufir             Sat Aug 25 17:05  15/439   ping
 N   4 thufir             Sat Aug 25 17:05  15/453   ping
? 
X-Original-To: thufir@localhost
To: thufir@localhost
Subject: hello world
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Date: Sat, 25 Aug 2012 17:04:32 -0700 (PDT)
From: hawat@localhost

hello world content yet again
? 
X-Original-To: thufir@localhost
To: <thufir@localhost>
Subject: cannot send to localhost
X-Mailer: mail (GNU Mailutils 2.2)
Date: Sat, 25 Aug 2012 21:41:42 +0000 (UTC)
From: thufir@dur (thufir)

ping
? 
X-Original-To: thufir@localhost
To: <thufir@localhost>
Cc: <thufir@dur.bounceme.net>
Subject: ping
X-Mailer: mail (GNU Mailutils 2.2)
Date: Sat, 25 Aug 2012 21:40:51 +0000 (UTC)
From: thufir@dur (thufir)


pong
? 
X-Original-To: thufir@dur.bounceme.net
To: <thufir@localhost>
Cc: <thufir@dur.bounceme.net>
Subject: ping
X-Mailer: mail (GNU Mailutils 2.2)
Date: Sat, 25 Aug 2012 21:40:51 +0000 (UTC)
From: thufir@dur (thufir)


pong
? 
No applicable message
? 
No applicable message
? q
Saved 4 messages in /home/thufir/mbox
Held 0 messages in /var/mail/thufir
thufir@dur:~$
```

which was all that I needed.

Comment: this was a very screwy problem -- if you are using this question/answer feel free to ask for more information.